# Trying to initialize SqsEvent records in Golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

Trying to write a test and mockup an SQS Event. What am I doing wrong ?:

```
    var sqsEvent events.SQSEvent

    mess := events.SQSMessage{
        Body: jsonString,
    }
    sqsEvent.Records = []{mess}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you declare message array is incorrect. Try:

```
sqsEvent.Records = []events.SQSMessage{mess}
```